# Can't make all user book resource in Room mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange-2019

I cannot understand why i cannot make reservation like normal user, when in setting of Room, i specified "Book delegates --> Accept or decline booking request automatically"

When I tried to create event i got error "You don't have permission to create an entry in this folder. Right-click folder, and select Properties to check your permissions for the folder. See the folder owner or your administrator to change your permission"

But when share mailbox through OWA of the Room mailbox, and set permission as Editor, I got access to make reservation, but i have then another problem i can not control when someone create another booking when the resource has already been taken, and no reject message to user.

I using Exchange 2019 and Outlook 2019.

Answer (score 0):

> When I tried to create event i got error "You don't have permission to create an entry in this folder. Right-click folder, and select Properties to check your permissions for the folder. See the folder owner or your administrator to change your permission"

Sounds like an expected behavior if you were trying to create the event directly from the room mailbox's calendar folder. It does require the editor permission to be granted. Here's a link discussing a relevant topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/813566/room-mailbox-permissions.

As mentioned in the link above and also in [this MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/room-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019#:%7E:text=Rooms%20should%20only%20be%20added%20to%20meetings%20by%20including%20them%20in%20the%20Attendee%20or%20Location%20fields.), although it's supported after granting the sufficient permissions, this is not the recommended approach to reserve a meeting room.  "**Rooms should only be added to meetings by including them in the Attendee or Location fields.**" And this is how we normally book a room in a meeting request.

> but i have then another problem i can not control when someone create
> another booking when the resource has already been taken, and no
> reject message to user.

So, do you mean you want to allow conflicting meeting requests? If this is the case, this setting can be modified if you are an Admin or a user with full access to the resource mailbox:

1. Log in to Outlook Web App and click on Your name in the top right corner.
2. Click **Open another mailbox**. Locate the meeting room mailbox you want and click **Open**.
3. Go to **settings** and click **Options**, **Calendar**.
4. Navigate to **Resource scheduling**.
5. Configure the Scheduling Options to allow conflicts.
   [image]
6. Click **Save** after you have finished making your changes.